# Change axis interval Dimple Library Javascript

Tags: javascript, web, graphics, dimple.js

I am using Dimple library for represent some graphics in a web application. Dimple represents my y axis with a interval and i want to change this interval.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid dimple doesn't currently support that.  Please could you create an issue in the GitHub repository for an enhancement?